# How calculate position of an element relative to screen

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, backbone.js

I'm developing a mobile app with backbone and I need to detect the position of an element in a list. I've tried with scrollTop property but return ever zero. So is there a technique to determine the position of element relative to screen? I've tried with this:

```
   var p = $( "li:first" );
   var position = p.offset();
   console.warn(position.top);
```

but on computer return some value and on mobile phone return different values.

Comment: also why do you want to get the screen coordinates of an HTML element? it does not make much sense, in most cases, we won't encounter this use case because the world of all HTML elements is confined to the web page (the document).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
var yRelativeToScreen = p.offset().top - window.scrollY;
```

Comment: window.scrollY return me ever zero,why?

Comment: @user1938193 because your page has no vertical scrollbar or with it located right at the top, this answer is wrong.

Comment: Ok,thankyou. Could you tell me how create vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @user1938193 I mean your page has little content and the vertical scrollbar won't appear. You should not care about that because that's not the right direction for you to go.

Comment: I've fixed css and now window.scrolly works but on mobile device return values a bit different than computer screen

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to do. If you need some sort of relative distance to something that should be the same on both desktop and mobile, maybe you are referring to the relative distance the li is to it's parent? If so, just use the `offset()` function and use subtraction.

Comment: Yes I'm try to calculate distance from li and its parent but console.log(p.offset().top - window.scrollY) return me differents value on mobile respect monitor pc.Why?@Kyle

Comment: so do: var topDiff = p.offset().top - p.parent().offset().top;